# doxygen copy specific data from doxygen comments into markdown page

Tags: c++, markdown, doxygen

I would like to know if there is a way to copy specific parts of doxygen comments from one file or multiple files into a markdown page. Below I describe what I am trying to do.

I am working on developing a C++ plugin code, which consists of several modules. Each module follows its version numbering scheme. In every plugin release, I pick a specific version number for each of the modules. To allow the end user to access this information programatically, I have set up a `namespace` as follows:

```
namespace VersionInfo {
    string getModuleA_Version() { return "2.3"; }
    string getModuleB_Version() { return "1.0"; }
    string getPlugin_Version() { return "10.11"; }
}
```

I also want this information to appear on a `README.md` markdown file. Is this possible with doxygen, and if so, how should I comment the above C++ code and the `README.md` file?

It is fine with me if I have to write the version number again in the C++ comment. For example:

```
// Sample pseudo-code
/**
  * @brief version number for module A.
  * @version_moduleA 2.3
  */
string getModuleA_Version() { return "2.3"; }
```

Is it possible to define custom variables as above, and then reference them in the markdown file? For example, something like:

```
// Sample pseudo-markdown
Versions
- ModuleA : @version_moduleA
- ModuleB : @version_moduleB
- ModuleC : @version_moduleC
```

I have tried going through the documentation on the doxygen home page, but I could not figure it out.

It would be helpful even if you point out the doxygen commands, I will try to work it out from there.

**Edit** @Zane's comment below made me think more about it. A solution as described above is preferred, but I think it is acceptable even if I could just *link* from the markdown file to the corresponding comment.

Comment: you can quote from source files using `@snippet` but afaik this will not work with markdown. Is markdown really necessary?

Comment: @Zane The markdown page `README.md` carries information about several other things related to the plugin (dependencies, installation, etc.), so I thought it would be nice to put this information there too. I _could_ do with that data excluded from the markdown page or with manually copying the data from the C++ file, but thought it would be less error-prone if done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I need to solve the same problem of inserting source code comments into markdown files.  My plan is to have doxygen output xml and put my own custom tag in the markdown file (like @xml_brief_description ).  Then write a post-processing script that parses the XML file and makes the appropriate substitutions in the markdown files.

If anyone has an easier way of accomplishing this then I'm all ears.